# Google Maps / TypeScript - Not Consistently Recognizing google.maps.Place

Tags: javascript, google-maps, typescript, google-maps-api-3

I am attempting to use Google's Map API in my application. However, I am receiving the following compiler error:

```
[ts] Property 'Place' does not exist on type 'typeof maps'. Did you mean 'places'?
```

Now, ordinarily I might assume that I am missing a typing or dependency or something; however the odd part is, the "Place" property is recongized correctly just a few lines above.

```
class gMap {
    latLong: google.maps.LatLng;
    window: google.maps.InfoWindow;
    marker: google.maps.Marker;
    map: google.maps.Map;
    directionsService: google.maps.DirectionsService;
    directionsDisplay: google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
    placeID: string;
    place: google.maps.Place;

constructor(lat: number, long: number, place: string, info: string, mapEl: Element) {
    this.latLong = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);
    this.window = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: info });
    this.placeID = place;
    this.place = new google.maps.Place(place);

    this.map = new google.maps.Map(mapEl, {
        center: this.latLong,
        zoom: 15
    });

    this.marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: this.latLong, map: this.map, });
    this.window.open(this.map, this.marker);

}
```

The first use of google.maps.Place (  place: google.maps.Place;) works. The one within the constructor ( this.place = new google.maps.Place(place);) is causing an error.

I apologize if this something obvious, I am relatively new to TypeScript and Google Maps. Any guidance would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `google.maps.Place`, according to the Google Maps JavaScript API documentation is not the class, it's an object:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Place

So, you cannot use a `new` operator to create an instance. You should treat it as a plain JavaScript object with properties `location`, `placeId` and `query`.